# Python SOAP call with requests lib no working as expected

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, suds, zeep

I have been trying to do a soap call using python and requests library, cause it is to much flexible on the xml file definition. I have tried with zeed and sud, unfortunately zeed doesnt let me to define portypes before I do the instance creation and suds doesnt let me change the enconding file, suds just work with utf-8, then I decide to use requests library for raw soap call. However the response is always status 500.

My questions are:

- What is wrong?
- What is the right way on run this soap call?

**Response**

```
response.status_code 500
response.text <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Code**

```
import os
import pystache
import requests
import base64
import urllib

from wsse.client.requests.auth import WSSEAuth


invoice_file_name = '10101010101-03-F004-00000001.zip'

invoice_file_path = 'path_to/10101010101-03-F004-00000001.zip'

with open(invoice_file_path, 'rb') as file:
    invoice_file_data = base64.b64encode(file.read())


xml_send_bill_path = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'templates',
    'send_bill.xml'
)
with open(xml_send_bill_path, 'r') as file:
    xml_send_bill = file.read()

xml_send_bill_string = pystache.render(xml_send_bill, {
    'SunatRUC': '20100066603',
    'SunatUser': 'MODDATOS',
    'SunatPass': 'moddatos',
    'InvoiceFileName': invoice_file_name,
    'InvoiceFileContent': invoice_file_data
})

WSDL_URL = 'https://e-factura.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpfegem/billService?wsdl'
#WSDL_URL = 'https://e-beta.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpfegem-beta/billService?wsdl';

encoded_request = xml_send_bill_string.encode('iso-8859-1')
headers = {
    'content-type': 'text/xml',
    'charset': 'iso-8859-1',
    "Content-Length": str(len(encoded_request))
}

response = requests.post(
    url=WSDL_URL,
    data=encoded_request,
    headers=headers,
    auth = WSSEAuth('20100066603MODDATOS', 'moddatos')
)

print ("response.status_code", response.status_code)
print ("response.text", response.text)
```

**XML Template**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='no'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.sunat.gob.pe" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security>
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>{{SunatRUC}}{{SunatUser}}</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>{{SunatPass}}</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:sendBill>
<fileName>{{InvoiceFileName}}</fileName>
<contentFile>{{{InvoiceFileContent}}}</contentFile>
</ser:sendBill>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What error return in the response ?

Comment: dont set the header `Content-Length` , requests will automatically set it and it should work

Comment: @ElinaldoMonteiro as the question content, the response is an error 500 status

Comment: @Stack unfortunately, I have also test this way without status 200

Comment: when you remove only this `"Content-Length": str(len(encoded_request))` , what is the status code? 500?

Comment: @Stack, yes, status is 500. I have tried it with zeep and it works whoeever headers are no according to the xml xpected by the sopa server, that is the reason on trying with responses lib

Comment: remove `content-length` and try with `{'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}`

Comment: 500 is a server error. There was is no reason to assume this is a fault on your part. Contact the site maintainers to ask them to fix their server.